Fixing a Septic Leach-Field Vent
My septic system's leach-field vent pipe cracked just underground. I think the pipe is Schedule 30, but I have free access to Schedule 40. Can I just use an adapter to go from Schedule 30 to 40 and make the vent pipe out of 40, or is that a bad idea? From what I've seen, the Schedule 40 will make the vent pipe bigger than I've seen in other yards, but if it will save me money by not having to buy any new pieces, I'm fine with it.
Thanks, all.

A fast search for 30 to 40 adapters show it is possible/adapters available.

Thanks for responding. I appreciate it. I've seen adapters for 30 to 40, but I'm wondering if there would be any issues with it either structurally or in terms of code.

Code can be more of a local matter if allowed or not.  For a vent pipe, it should be structurally okay, unless an excessive length free standing.

Thanks. Much appreciated.
